# Twitter API to take a tweet from and use it in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, twitter

Is there an API that will take a twitter tweet and convert it to a string to be used in a program or website?

Comment: I don't get it, what is that you need? Want to search for a tweet? Last tweet of a certain user? Something else? Just for display using javascript or for processing using a server-sided implementation?

Comment: @fijter, take a tweet that has a specific hashtag from a specific person and convert it to a string to be used in a program.  It would be used for processing server-sided implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc) documentation. The [streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api) may be helpful to you. In addition, [This will show an individual status](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/show/%3aid)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.get('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show/81432962704482304.json', function(data) { 
    console.log(data); 
});
```

You can use jQuery to retrieve data from the Twitter api. 
http://dev.twitter.com/doc